# Does the patients relieved from COVID 19 become resistant to the corona virus species?

Tags: covid-19, coronavirus

COVID 19 is spreading very fast and took about half a lakh lives.if the patients does not become resistant to these virus just like chickenpox,is it possible to break the chain?

Comment: This is an English language forum. Do not use Indian words.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be referring to the concept of heterologous immunity. This is when immunity to one virus confers some immunity to other pathogens too. There is a great review by Pusch et al (citation below) that indicates that there may be some degree of heterologous immunity between coronaviruses. Specifically, vaccination with a viral vaccine vector encoding a SARS-CoV CD4+ T cell epitope protected mice from infection with MERS-CoV, another coronavirus. However, by and large, infection with one coronavirus does not completely protect you from infections with other coronaviruses.

Pusch, E., Renz, H. & Skevaki, C. Respiratory virus-induced heterologous immunity. Allergo J Int 27, 79–96 (2018). https://doi-org.ezproxy.med.cornell.edu/10.1007/s40629-018-0056-0

Comment: Don't think that's the question.